# Event click doesn't work when navigate in vueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, click, vuex, show-hide

I've a menu, it's going to expand when you click over the arrow, and if you click again is going to contract. I develop this option adding a css class (.show) to a div. The problem happens when I navigate to another page and I'll try to show/hide the menu clicking in the arrow, in this moment nothing happens...**Why click's event dissapear?** **@click could lost the funcionality if you change the router-view ?**

```js
function showNav () {
  if (this.$store.getters.showSidebar) {
    this.$store.commit(SET_SHOW_LINK, false)
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$store.commit(SET_SHOW_SIDEBAR, false)
    }, 500)
  } else {
    this.$store.commit(SET_SHOW_SIDEBAR, true)
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$store.commit(SET_SHOW_LINK, true)
    }, 500)
  }
}
```

```css
.container-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 65px;
  right: 0;
  width: 50px;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #072146;
  border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 0 0 1px;
  z-index: 999;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;

  .control {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    //width: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    i {
      font-size: 2rem;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    }
  }

  &.show {
    width: 160px;
    .control > i {
      color: #fff;
      transform: rotateZ(-180deg);
    }
  }

  .navigation-icons-menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50px;
    float: right;
    i {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 2rem;
      padding: 10px 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
      &:hover {
        color: #fff;
      }
    }
  }
  .navigation-links-menu {
    //padding:14px;
    float: right;
    color: #fff;
    div {
      font-size: 1.35rem;
      padding: 10px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation__menu">
 <div
   class="container-menu"
   :class="{'show': this.$store.getters.showSidebar}">
   <div
  class="control"
  @click="showNav">
  <i
    class="fas fa-angle-double-left" />
   </div>
   <div class="navigation-links-menu">
  <transition-group name="fade">
    <div
   v-show="this.$store.getters.showLink"
   key="1">Home</div>
    <div
   v-show="this.$store.getters.showLink"
   key="2">FIG</div>
    <div
   v-show="this.$store.getters.showLink"
   key="3">Validation</div>
    <div
   v-show="this.$store.getters.showLink"
   key="4">Authorization</div>
  </transition-group>
   </div>
   <div class="navigation-icons-menu">
  <router-link :to="`/`"><i class="fas fa-home" /></router-link>
  <router-link :to="`/console`"><i class="fas fa-clipboard-list" /></router-link>
  <i class="fas fa-check" />
  <i class="fas fa-check-double" />
   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution may be changing your mutation to toggle the `showSidebar` state instead of setting it. This will allow you to remove your if/else flows and not to worry about the current state.

```
function showNav () {
    this.$store.commit(TOGGLE_SHOW_LINK)
    setTimeout((vue) => {
      vue.$store.commit(TOGGLE_SHOW_SIDEBAR)
    }, 500, this)
}

// mutations.js

mutations: {
    TOGGLE_SHOW_SIDEBAR (state) {
        state.showSidebar = !state.showSidebar
    },
    TOGGLE_SHOW_LINK (state) {
        state.showLink = !state.showLink
    }
}
```

When you check the state with your getter like below, you're probably expecting your `this.$store.getters.showSidebar` to become true when it's false, but you're missing this 500ms benchmark between clicks.

```
  if (this.$store.getters.showSidebar) {
    this.$store.commit(SET_SHOW_LINK, false)
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$store.commit(SET_SHOW_SIDEBAR, false)
    }, 500)
  } else {
    this.$store.commit(SET_SHOW_SIDEBAR, true)
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.$store.commit(SET_SHOW_LINK, true)
    }, 500)
  }
```

Another solution I recommend is disabling the element that calls showNav, until the timeout ends, but the first solution may be enough.